# undefined method `upload_path' - 'new' action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This should be super simple, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. 
The form in the 'new' page for uploads is getting an error.

- 'Uploads' belong to 'Event'
- 'Event' has many 'Uploads'
- routes.rb is (as far as I know) correct.
- I'm planning on using Refile to upload files to S3 (as per [this](http://cecycorrea.com/2015/07/22/rails-refile-tutorial.html) tutorial... not sure if this is relevant at all though)

**Upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  attachment :upload_file
end
```

**Event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :uploads
end
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event

  def new
    @upload = @event.uploads.create
  end


  private
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root 'pages#home'

  resources :events do
    resources :coupons
    resources :uploads
    member do
      post :check
    end
  end
```

**views/uploads/new.html.erb (example)**

```
<%= form_for @upload do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

When I navigate to the 'new' page, I get the following error:

*undefined method `upload_path' for #<#:0x007fb8709229f0>*

Why can't I add a new Upload associated with Event? I know I'm missing something super simple, but I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `uploads` is nested in `events`, you get url for your upload path as follow:

`/events/1/uploads/new`

In this case, you have to specify @event in your `form_for` method like this:

`<%= form_for [@event, @upload] do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

`<%= form_for @event.upload do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end%>`